# Polish dictionary database - weird symbols (subst:sg:voc:f) - what are they?

Tags: string, language-agnostic

As in the title, I am working with database containing a Polish dictionary where one of the columns contains records such as:

```
subst:sg:voc:f
subst:pl:nom.voc:m1
subst:sg:dat:m3
```

What are those tags? What are they called? How do I read them?

Comment: Care to tell use what “Polish dictionary” you are talking about?

Comment: and this doesn't appear to have anything to do with programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing anything else about the dictionary (nor polish) they appear to be:

- type of word (substantive, verb, adjective, etc)
- number (sg: singular, pl: plural)
- decliantion (voc: vocative, dat: dative)
- gender and person (f: feminine, m1: masculine first person, m3: masculine third person)

Comment: Yeah, that's it, you maybe know a term for those tags? If I wanted to search google for more info, what would I look for?

Comment: I would name them a "categorization" of a term or word. I know for a fact that the technical term for "type of word" is lexical category